# What are the default character separators for boost::char_separator (for use with boost::tokenizer)?

Tags: c++, boost, boost-tokenizer

The answer to this question seems like it should be easily obtainable by looking at the Boost documentation for `char_separator`, or by googling.

However, nowhere can I find the answer to this question: What are the default separators for `boost::char_separator` (for use with `boost::tokenizer`)?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/tokenizer/introduc.htm

> ...  If you do not specify anything, the default TokenizerFunction is char_delimiters_separator which **defaults to breaking up a string based on space and punctuation**. ...

According to the source code, "punctuation" is defined as `std::ispunct(E) != 0`, while "space" is defined as `std::isspace(E) != 0`.

Comment: Which punctuation, do you know?

Comment: It calls `std::ispunct()` to check.